# Loop to assign the height

Tags: jquery, css, height

I want to assign the height of a div and assign it to another with jQuery.
This with a loop for several div.
The second div is on two lines.

It works on Mac Chrome, IE PC, but not on Chrome PC.

I do not get the right value.
Mac I get 37 for the first and 74 the second.
PC are both 37.

Thanks for your help. :)

```js
$('.display-block.title-node-information').each(function() {
 var height = 0;
  console.log($(this).height());

});
```

```css
.title-node-information{
  font-size: 39px;
 font-family: 'Gotham Black';
  line-height: 37px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bord">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="display-block title-node-information">Hello</div>
</div>
<div class="bord">
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="display-block title-node-information">Concerts &amp; spectacles</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I use chrome on a PC and this is showing 37 and 74

Comment: Yes me too with "run code snippet".
I don't understand, but in my page i have as height.

Maybe, clear both div parent? i'm lost

Comment: I can send you the link to my page to see if you have an idea please?
Thanks :)

Comment: Hi every body. Thanks for your answers et your help. 
The problem comes from a div that had no height. I work with drupal and he created with no css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you resize your window then height of both DIVs will be changed..try this..even though you have given width:30% and if you minimize or resize window then it will change..hope this gives you clear answer